# How to doctest random.sample() when used on a set?

Tags: python, random, set, doctest, random-seed

I am trying to write a doctest for a function that calls `random.sample()` on a set. Unfortunately, it seems that seeding is not sufficient to guarantee an output.

Consider the following:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.seed(1)
>>> s = set(('Ut', 'Duis', 'Lorem', 'Excepteur'))
>>> for _ in range(5): print(random.sample(s,1))
... 
['Duis']
['Ut']
['Excepteur']
['Ut']
['Lorem']
>>> random.seed(1)
>>> for _ in range(5): print(random.sample(s,1))
... 
['Duis']
['Ut']
['Excepteur']
['Ut']
['Lorem']
```

But if I reinstantiate the Python interpreter:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.seed(1)
>>> s = set(('Ut', 'Duis', 'Lorem', 'Excepteur'))
>>> for _ in range(5): print(random.sample(s,1))
... 
['Duis']
['Lorem']
['Ut']
['Lorem']
['Excepteur']
```

Namely, seeding `random` with the same value does not guarantee the same output across Python instances. I expect that this problem is specific to the implementation of set in Python. Any ideas for how to write a doctest for this scenario?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What Python version are you on?

Comment: I am using Python 3.4—sorry for not specifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occurs because `random.sample(s, 1)` calls `list(s)` internally, thus flattening the set into a list in a nondeterministic order.  This occurs before trying to use the `random.random()` function.  The problem with writing a doctest is the same as writing a doctest to check a set: you can't, so you need workarounds like checking `sorted(s)`.

In the simplest cases you can solve it by calling `random.sample(sorted(s), 1)`.  If the code is more involved and it doesn't make sense to add `sorted()` there in production, all I can say is good luck...

Comment: "writing a doctest to check a set: you can't"  Why?  They test equal.

Comment: I'm talking about doctests specifically, which is a testing framework which is not about checking that objects are equal, but that their *repr* is as expected.